# How to print a list of value from Cs page to presentation layer(Aspx)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I have a list object in **Cs** page with 2Row.
How to get it separately in **Aspx page**
Eg:
 For a single value It will be:

```
$("#txtBilldate").val(data.d.lphBillDate);
```

How to get a list ,like the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Send it to ASPX As array by using LINQ and access it..

```
       return list       
              .Select(a => new
              {
                  a.column1,
                  a.column2,
                  a.column3
              }).ToArray();
```

Access it by using JS

```
 var models = (typeof result.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + result.d + ')') : result.d;

for (var i = 0; i < models.length; i++) {
      $("#txtBilldate").val(models[i].column1);
    }
```